# Why do freenet keys have a maximum file (data block) size?

Tags: file, distribution, block, distributed-computing, filesize

In Freenet, if a file is large, [it is split](http://wiki.freenetproject.org/SplitFile) into datablocks and what is called a splitfile, contains keys to all these blocks. Why is this necessary?

The only possible explanation I could draw from it is that they want the possibility of a hash collision to be minimal.

**NOTE:** I've posted this in StackOverflow because I believe it is a programming problem of sorts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a freenet expert, but... splitting files into small chunks has several benefits:

- The "burden" of large files are split across nodes. This means that even nodes who have only set a small amount of storage or bandwidth aside for freenet can help store and deliver parts of larger files.
- Nodes in freenet are not guaranteed to be stable. If a node goes offline during the storing or fetching small chunks little effort is lost and another node can be used instead without added protocol complexity.
- Chunks can be stored and fetched in parallel allowing for very fast transfers despite a network of slow nodes.